# Accessing Ninject objects from master view partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject

I am trying to access an object created by ninject within my layout view but I have no idea how to access them.

Here is a brief outline of what I have tried so far:-

Created by service and bound them:

```
public interface IService 
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void SomeMethod
    {

    }
}

Bind<IService>().To<Service>();
```

Created a static class and use the `[Inject]` attribute:

```
public static class MasterLayout
{
    [Inject]
    public static IService Service { private get; set; }

    public static void CallSomeMethod();
    {
        Service.SomeMethod
    }
}
```

Everytime I call `MasterLayout.CallSomeMethod()` from **my master view or partial view**, the `Service` field is always null.

Is this even possible or should I be creating a base Controller and getting other controllers to inherit from it where I can set those values to be used within the master view and partial views?  Is there an even better way of achieving this?

Comment: statics dont get injected (there are other questions covering this)

Comment: Thanks Ruben - I had found a few questions similar to what I asked but not explicitly around static classes/methods/properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Ninject work if used with contructor injection?

( see http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Injection%20Patterns )

Something like

```
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

    public AccountController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

Have you checked here?

[bind to property always return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108352/bind-to-property-always-return-null)

When you say "on every page", you mean "on every controller"?

If yes, i think you could create a BaseController class, and all the controllers should inherit from it. I'm using this method.

Comment: Yup, that works fine, I can access all my services that are created through the controllers without any issue at all.  I want to access the services through the master layout (_Layout.cshtml) rather than a view.  I need this information to be places on every page that is loaded throughout the application

Comment: Have you checked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108352/bind-to-property-always-return-null

Comment: When you say "on every page", you mean "on every controller"? If yes, i think you could create a BaseController class, and all the controllers should inherit from it. I'm using this method.

Comment: I agree, if you create a new answer/amend your answer I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [custom controller factory](http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/mvc-controller-factory-ninject/) to have Ninject create the controllers.  Once you do, this will work.  There is also probably [an extension](http://www.ninject.org/extensions.html) for this already.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out I am using the Ninject.MVC3 package so the binding is already done...